# sshing into remote as someone else

Tags: ssh

I can ssh into remote_box and when I am in remote_box my userid is dorelal and I am at /home/dorelal. I have only one entry in my .ssh/authorized_keys and that is my id_rsa.pub .

There is an account for user 'deploy'. 
User deploy already has a .ssh directory and has a authorized_keys file.

I want to login to remote_box as 'deploy'. In order to do that this is what I did.

```
/home/deploy/.ssh/authorized_keys << /home/dorelal/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

However when I try deploy@remote_box I am getting Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to put the public key of dorelal to authorized_keys of deploy. The public key is placed in a .pub file in the .ssh directory of dorelal.

```
cat /home/dorelal/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> /home/deploy/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: there were some weird white space issue. got resolved. it is working. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Likely, you've got incorrect permissions.  Check your secure log (/var/log/secure on many systems) to be sure.  If you need to correct them, just do:

```
chown -R deploy. /home/deploy/.ssh
chmod 700 /home/deploy/.ssh
chmod 600 /home/deploy/.ssh/authorized_keys
```